# Getting Azure Operation Status with Microsoft Azure Management Libraries

Tags: azure

The following page describes how to get Operation Status with the REST API.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460783.aspx

Is it possible to get that Operation Status with the Microsoft Azure Management Libraries found at https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Libraries ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Assuming you have an instance of the **ManagementClient** class, the method is **GetOperationStatus**.  You pass in the RequestId of the request you want to get the status of.

Also, this method exists for specific resource clients too. For example, the WebSiteManagementClient class exposes this method.